# File Writer - All going on one Line

Tags: java, filewriter

I have the following code:

```
File aFile = new File("data.txt");

try {
   FileWriter aFileWriter = new FileWriter(aFile);
   aFileWriter.write("Hello.\n");
   aFileWriter.write("This is.\n");
   aFileWriter.write("A Test.\n");
}
catch (Exception anException){
   System.out.println("Error: " + anException);
}
```

This is supposed to write

```
Hello.
This is.
A Test.
```

but on to three different lines. As you can see I included `\n` as a line separator, but it does not seem to work.

Does anyone know how to get the line separator to work correctly please?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Did you read the whole question ? Please do read the questions before you marking them duplicates.

Comment: The marked duplicate question doesn't have anything to do with this question.

Comment: He did specify it. It was not formatted, but present.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis If you read carefully, you find the line `but on to three different lines. As you can see I included \n as a line separator, but it does not seem to work/`

Comment: You guys must be correct, given the title.

Comment: Thanks all -  System.getProperty("line.separator") worked!